# invalid operands to binary expression - when removing object

Tags: c++

I want to remove an object from an array.
The problem is that i don't know the index, so i try the remove method.

The method is definded like this:

```
void ofxDTangibleManager::updateList(vector<ofxDTangible> &oldList, vector<ofxDTangible> &newList) {
```

Here is the part where it goes wrong:

```
for(int i = 0; i < oldList.size(); i++) {

    if(newList.size() == 0) {
        break;
    }

    ofxDTangible &t = oldList[i];

    ofxDTangible &closest = getClosestTangible(t, newList, false);

    float d = distSquared(t, closest);

    if(d < maxMoveDistSquared) {
        refound[i] = true;
        // copy values of new one over
        // todo
        // set as target so we can interpoplate if required

        // remove it so we make sure we don't assign it to multiple tangibles
        remove(newList.begin(), newList.end(), closest);
    }
}
```

This are the errors:
[image: error]

How can i get around this problem?

Comment: `std::remove` doesn't remove them. `std::<Container>::erase` does.

Comment: How can i use erase without knowing the index?

Comment: It generally takes an iterator. You're already searching through the container for it by using `std::remove`, so `std::find` would be the same time. I'm going to hazard a guess that either way without a custom comparator, you're going to get errors because there's no `operator==`.

Comment: I don't quit follow you, i have to make a `operator==` for my `ofxDTangible` class?

Comment: Either that or passing a custom comparator to `find/remove`. They have to know if the current element is the same as the one you pass in. Of course, there might be a better way of getting an iterator than `find` that I don't know from the code.

Comment: Make `getClosestTangible` return an iterator, then you can both get the value and efficiently erase.